# Playwright evaluate function close the web browser

Tags: javascript, automation, playwright

I don't have a lot of experience but started using playwright and it runs manually using the pause method but when I run it automated it closes the browser quickly. Thing to note, it does takes time when I do it manually. Any idea what can I do?

```
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');

test('has title', async ({ page }) => {


  
  //Opens zillow and log the user in
  await page.goto('https://www.zillow.com');
  // await page.pause();

  // //It closes the google popup
  await page.frameLocator('iframe[title="Sign in with Google Dialog"]').getByLabel('Close').click();
  await page.getByRole('link', { name: 'Sign In' }).click();
  
  //Add your email and password to the fill strings
  await page.getByPlaceholder('Enter email').fill("NEED EMAIL");
  await page.getByPlaceholder('Enter password').fill("NEED PASS");
  await page.getByRole('button', {name: 'Sign in'}).click();
  await page.waitForTimeout(2000);
  
  //Searchbar fill
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Got it!' }).click();
  await page.getByPlaceholder('Enter an address, neighborhood, city, or ZIP code').fill("Chattanooga");
  await page.waitForTimeout(2000);
  await page.getByRole('button', {name: 'Submit Search'}).click();
  await page.waitForTimeout(2000);
  // await page.pause();
  
  const ulElement = await page.$$('.List-c11n-8-84-3__sc-1smrmqp-0.StyledSearchListWrapper-srp__sc-1ieen0c-0.doa-doM.fgiidE.photo-cards.photo-cards_extra-attribution li');
if (ulElement.length > 0) {
 // Process each li element in the array
 for (const liElement of ulElement) {
   const textContent = await page.evaluate(li => li.textContent, liElement);

   if (textContent?.includes('37421')) {
     const button = await liElement.$('button');
     if (button) {
       await button.click();
       console.log('Text content of li element:', textContent);
     }
   }
 }

} else {
 console.log('No li elements found inside the ul with role="list".');
}
});
```

I tried adding timeouts like await page.waitForTimeout(2000); but it doesn't work

Comment: Without a username and password, it'll still be non-reproducible though, even after moving the code to the question.

Comment: Got it thanks for letting me know, I moved the code to the original question. About the username and password I was using a personal one I deleted the info from there and added the words so the user can put their zillow account and then it should run

Answer (score 0):

###### Instead of Hard coded wait, use [toBeVisible](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-be-visible) to verify post login/submit state

> toBeVisible is a *locator assertion* which means it would wait and
> retry for an object to reach the expected state until timeout but at
> the same time its flexible enough as well to move forward if object appears early
> unlike hard coded wait.

**Note**: You can adjust the timeout argument value based on your case.

#### Few Usage Examples

```
// A specific element is visible.
await expect(page.getByText('Welcome'+ userName)).toBeVisible({timeout:5000})

// At least one item in the list is visible.
await expect(page.getByTestId('todo-item').first()).toBeVisible()

// At least one of the two elements is visible, possibly both.
await expect(
    page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sign in' })
        .or(page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sign up' }))
        .first()
).toBeVisible()
```

#### Few More Pointers:

1. Don't use hardcoded waits , instead use [Locators Assertions](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-be-visible) as they are dynamic and will not wait unnecessarily.
2. Don't use $$ to identify objects , use [locators](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator) as its dynamic so that you will not get into issues like 'Stale Element Reference Error' (if you are from selenium world you would understand it!)
3. Don't use JS level properties like 'length' instead use playwright API methods like [count](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-count) to get more reliable & consistent results.

Comment: Thanks both of you for the help. I did more digging after reading both of your answers and I found out that my problem was that playwright had a built in time limit of 3 seconds. I had to add a test.setTimeout(200000); and it run perfectly now.